# Sum of fractions in the form $\frac{1}{n}$ from $\frac{1}{2^n}$ to $\frac{1}{3*2^{(n-1)} - 1}$ less than $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, computational-geometry, packing-problem

https://mathoverflow.net/a/278290/501460

I've been trying to figure out why this works, and why the tiles don't go past the middle, considering all the squares together have an infinite side length.

Is there an easy way to show that the range of fractions in each layer doesn't add up to over $\frac12$ (and similarly, the ones starting from the right that range from, I believe, $\frac{1}{3*2^{(n-1)}}$ to $\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)} - 1}$ don't add up to over $\frac13$)

Comment: Can you compare this sum to an integral?  We get bound $\ln(3/2) \approx 0.4$.

Comment: Hint: how many fractions are you summing? What's their maximum value? For which $n$ is at least one fraction less than this maximum?

Comment: @J.G. with the first term as $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (which is also the max value), there should be $2^{n} - 1$ squares until we move to the next "layer" - not too sure exactly where to go with this

Comment: @GEdgar apologies, I don't really understand why bound = ln(3/2). it also seems to not work for n = 1 and 2, at least, as they sum to 0.50 and 0.45 (based on layout here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/278290/501460)

Comment: In fact we get the sum is $> \log(3/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $1/x$ is decreasing.
$$
\sum_{k=2^n}^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1} \frac{1}{k}
< \int_{2^n-1}^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
=\log(3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1)-\log(2^n-1)
=\log\frac{3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1}{2^n-1}
$$
This is decreasing as $n$ increases.  For $n \ge 3$ this is $< \frac12$.

Comment: Okay, it seems I am just bad at reading. Thank you for further clarifying, I appreciate it

Comment: Corrected.  In fact my first proof showed the sum is $> \log(3/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Without any serious maths: Count the number of fractions you are adding, then find a trivial upper and lower bound for each fraction, multiply and - voila - you have an upper and lower bound for the sum.

For a very precise estimate: 1/n is the integral of 1/x over the interval from n-1/2 to n+1/2, plus a tiny correction. You can easily sum up integrals where the upper and lower limits match up, and the sum of the corrections is tiny.